# Docker network & depends_on

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Возникло недопонимание с `docker-network` и с `depends_on`.
Вопрос по основной части сетей я уже задавал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154020/docker-networking) .

## Первый вопрос:

`depends_on` работает достаточно странно в моем случае.
Я создал 2 тестовых `image`'a и имею следующую конфигурацию `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app1:
    image: test
    build: app1
    command: python3 app1.py
  app2:
    image: test2
    build: .
    depends_on:
        - app1
```

Но в логах все равно первым почему то запускается контейнер от `app2`:

```
root@icyftl:~/temp# docker-compose up
Building app2
Step 1/4 : from ubuntu:latest
 ---> 1e4467b07108
Step 2/4 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 08682223c800
Step 3/4 : RUN apt-get install curl -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6c6b82a3dca4
Step 4/4 : RUN curl http://app1:8000/test
 ---> Running in ad21307744f6
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to app1 port 8000: Connection refused
ERROR: Service 'app2' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl http://app1:8000/test' returned a non-zero code: 7
```

Как следствие, мои попытки понять проблему, которую я опишу во втором вопросе обрываются.

## Второй вопрос:

Как поднять сервер на `flask` в контейнере и обращаться к нему из другого контейнера?

При создании связки контейнеров в `docker-compose.yml`, как я уже понял - автоматом поднимается `bridge`.
Если я могу сделать `ping -c 100 app1` из второго контейнера и он будет работать, то как мне обращаться к серверу на `flask`, который поднят на `0.0.0.0`? `curl http://app1:8000/test`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая проблема возникает потому, что обращение в `app1` идет на этапе сборки, т.е. у вас в `Dockerfile` для `app2` есть команда которая пробует обращаться к `app2`: `RUN curl http://app1:8000/test`

А на этапе сборки `app1` еще не запущен.

По второму вопросу ответ, утвердительный. Если обо сервиса в одной сети (по умолчанию для сервисов из одного compose файла это так), то контейнер каждого из них доступен другому по hostname, который совпадает с именем сервиса в compose файле.